# MVC3 Authorize: Is It Bad Form to Call an Authorized Action from another Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, redirecttoaction, authorize-attribute

Is it required to use `RedirectToAction` when calling a controller action from another action? I currently just call them directly because I do not want them to return, and thus I bypass the Authorize tag to one of my actions (which does what I want).

Can you please let me know if this is bad form, and if so, should I create multiple new actions to set the client cookies or just set them directly in the `LogOn()` Action?

Can I instead make `SwitchClient` private, and then make a public Authorized action to be used only by Administrators on the client-side? Then, the private action would be called via the `LogOn` action, but cannot be accessed unless the users are authenticated as Administrators.

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [CustomAuthorizeAccess(Roles = "Administrator", RedirectResultUrl = "Unauthorized")]
        public ActionResult SwitchClient(string client)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["Client"] == null)
            {
                HttpCookie clientCookie = new HttpCookie("Client", client);
                Response.Cookies.Add(clientCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["Client"].Value = client;
            }
                return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Add user's role to cookies (assumes each user only has one role)
                        string role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).First();
                        HttpCookie roleCookie = new HttpCookie("Role", role);
                        if (role == "client1")
                        {
                            SwitchClient("client1");
                        }
                        else if (role == "client2")
                        {
                          SwitchClient("client2");
                        }
                        else if (role == "Administrator" || role == "client3")
                        {
                           SwitchClient("client3");
                        }
                        //Make role cookie persistent for 7 days
                        //if user selected "Remember Me"
                        if (model.RememberMe)
                        {
                            roleCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7);
                        }
                        if (Response.Cookies["Role"] != null)
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["Role"].Value = null;
                            Response.Cookies.Remove("Role");
                        }
                        Response.Cookies.Add(roleCookie);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Does this bypass the authorization? If so then -- absolutely don't do it. There is a difference between internal and external methods (be it just public/private or exposed/not-exposed to a service).

Comment: As far as I can tell it does bypass, because in the `LogOn()` Action, I've already called `FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);` before I call the `SwitchClient` (and this works for any client, no matter whether they are `Administrator` role or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the "switch client" logic into a private method or a utility class. Both controller action methods would call the private method.

This way the code and your intent would be less confusing.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was thinking after I read pst's comment!